# IE conditional stylesheet not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, conditional-statements, stylesheet

There is a lot of reading material when you Google something like “IE separate style sheet”, but not a lot of examples.

I have the following conditional CSS for IE7, right after my main style.

I would like the `margin-top` to be larger in IE7.

```php
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/ie7.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/ie8.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

In my main stylesheet I have this:

```css
.outerBlue_s {
    width: 230px; 
    height: 260px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #cccccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #cccccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #cccccc;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
    vertical-align:middle;
```

In the IE stylesheet I have only put the desired margin:

```css
.outerBlue_s {
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

Despite doing this, the margin is not changing when I check IE7.

Any help and advice is appreciated.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://fafaradesigns.com/wp/wp-content/themes/fafaradesigns/style.css" />
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fafaradesigns.com/wp/wp-content/themes/fafaradesigns/ie7.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fafaradesigns.com/wp/wp-content/themes/fafaradesigns/ie8.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

It doesn't look like the ie7 sheet is being referenced. What am I doing wrong?

I wound up going with a hack by putting conditional styles inline on each individual page:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style>
.innerBlue_c  {
margin-top: 1.5em;
}
</style>
```

I would rather have gone with the external separate ie stylesheet so the code was cleaner - but I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working. Did the conditional statement look wrong?

Comment: When you do View Source, does the actual stylesheet location show up? For that matter, can you put the resulting HTML in here, rather than the PHP?

Comment: And I can't fathom why you would want one particular browser to have different margins that the others, but I'm sure you have your reasons.

Comment: I used a css trick I ran across to vertically align using display:table, but unfortunately ie7 won't undertand that. That is the only reason I wanted the the ie7 margin to be different than the other browsers.

Comment: @MrLister when I view source in internet explorer I get the above

Comment: There is no CSS file at that location that I can see.

Comment: I wound up going with a hack by putting conditional styles inline on each individual page. I would rather have gone with the external separate ie stylesheet so the code was cleaner - but I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working. Did the conditional statement look wrong?

Comment: No, but http://www.fafaradesigns.com/wp/wp-content/themes/fafaradesigns/ie7.css/ is not the correct location of the stylesheet. You should find out where it is!

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for your attention - but I was actually testing on my local MAMP before I put it online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I finally got the external stylesheet to load using Monderizr and the same conditional code that I initially listed. Seems all I had to do was add an .ie7 in front of the styles in the external sheet.

Example of the Code that worked:

```
.ie7 #nav li {
    z-index: 102;
}
```